# How can I retrieve a nested type with its fully qualified name?

Tags: c#, nested, roslyn

I cannot seem to retrieve a nested class using Roslyn's `Compilation.GetTypeByMetaDataName()` method.

For example:

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
using System;
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass 
    {
        public class MyInnerClass
        {
        }
    }
}
");

var Mscorlib = new MetadataFileReference(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation",
    syntaxTrees: new[] { tree }, references: new[] { Mscorlib });

//Correctly retrieves outer type.
var outerClass = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("MyNamespace.MyClass");
//Cannot correctly retrieve inner type (returns null)
var innerClass = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("MyNamespace.MyClass.MyInnerClass");
```

Is it possible to retrieve nested types using their fully qualified names?

I realize one work around would be to first check if the containing type contained any types using `INamespaceorTypeSymbol.GetTypeMembers()`, but I would much rather not go down that path. I'd assume the `GetTypeByMetaDataName()` method should work for any type, nested or otherwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `+` to separate inner classes:

```
var innerClass = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("MyNamespace.MyClass+MyInnerClass");
```

The documentation for the [`Type.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method discusses the syntax used for naming nested types.